# How to echo element from object that has []

Tags: php, object

I'm trying to echo from the next object the sdasdad value

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [MAX(loc)] => sdasdad )
```

Problem is that when doing something like

```
echo $array[0]->[MAX(loc)]
```

or

```
echo $array[0]->MAX(loc)
```

or

```
echo $array[0]->{MAX(loc)}
```

it always results in an error. I'd appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $array[0]->{'[MAX(loc)]'}
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(unic) as canci

echo $array[0]->canci;
```